# Change the format of multiple columns, but exclude the first row and only include up to the last row with data in it

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have some code that changes the number format of columns Y to BB to decimal type. This is fine, however, I'd like a more efficient solution that doesn't include the first row, and stops at the last row with data in it. It should also consider the fact that there may be gaps in the data for each column.

```vb
Sheet2.Range("Y:BB").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

I have also tried the below, but it didn't work.

```vb
Sheet2.Range("Y2:BB2").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Comment: Do all the columns have the same length (last filled row)?

Comment: No, some columns have more rows than others, so I'd like the solution to only format each column up until the very last cell with a value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, URrng As Range, lastRow As Long
 
 Set sh = Sheet2
 Set URrng = sh.UsedRange
  lastRow = URrng.rows.count + URrng.row - 1 'last row of the used range
  sh.Range("Y2:BB" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```